# How to calculate RSI in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, recursive-query

Can somebody give me an idea how to calculate the RSI (Relative Strength Index)?

The formula for RSI:

```
100 - 100 / (1 + RS)

RS (Relative Strength) = AverageGain / AverageLoss
```

RSI calculation is based on 14 periods. Losses are expressed as positive values, not negative values.

The very first calculations for average gain and average loss are simple 14-period averages:

- First Average Gain = Sum of Gains over the past 14 periods / 14
- First Average Loss = Sum of Losses over the past 14 periods / 14

The second, and subsequent, calculations are based on the prior averages and the current gain loss:

- Average Gain = [(previous Average Gain) x 13 + current Gain] / 14.
- Average Loss = [(previous Average Loss) x 13 + current Loss] / 14.

Below is my query which is not working because something in my recursion part is wrong. The way I calculate `ROW_NUMBER`: my first row is relative to the most recent trading day. I also make calculations over a 250 periods because of additional explanations, not relative to the calculation:

```
WITH bas AS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             p.CurrentTicker, p.ClosePrice, p.PriceDate, p.ClosePriceChange, 
             (CASE WHEN p.ClosePriceChange > 0 THEN p.ClosePriceChange ELSE 0 END) Gain,
             (CASE WHEN p.ClosePriceChange < 0 THEN ABS(p.ClosePriceChange) ELSE 0 END) Loss,
             rownum 
         FROM
             (SELECT 
                  *, 
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CurrentTicker ORDER BY PriceDate DESC) rownum
              FROM 
                  PriceHistory
              WHERE 
                  PriceDate >= DATEADD(day, -400, GETDATE())) p 
         INNER JOIN 
             Ticker t ON p.CurrentTicker = t.CurrentTicker
         WHERE 
             rownum <= 250) a
),
rec AS 
(
    SELECT 
        CurrentTicker, PriceDate, ClosePriceChange, rownum,
        AvgGain = SUM(Gain) OVER (PARTITION BY CurrentTicker ORDER BY PriceDate ROWS BETWEEN 13 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW) / 14,
        AvgLoss = SUM(Loss) OVER (PARTITION BY CurrentTicker ORDER BY PriceDate ROWS BETWEEN 13 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW) / 14
    FROM 
        bas 
    WHERE 
        rownum = (SELECT MAX(rownum) - 14 FROM bas)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        bas.CurrentTicker, bas.PriceDate, bas.ClosePriceChange, bas.rownum,
        a.AvgGain, a.AvgLoss
    FROM 
        rec 
    INNER JOIN 
        bas ON rec.rownum - 1 = bas.rownum
        AND rec.CurrentTicker = bas.CurrentTicker
    CROSS APPLY 
        (SELECT 
             (rec.AvgGain * 13 + bas.Gain) / 14 AS AvgGain,
             (rec.AvgLoss * 13 + bas.Loss)/14 as AvgLoss) a
)
SELECT * 
FROM rec
WHERE CurrentTicker = 'AAPL'
ORDER BY PriceDate DESC
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Here is AAPL prices table:

| PriceDate | ClosePrice |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-23 | 125.86 |
| 2021-02-22 | 126 |
| 2021-02-19 | 129.87 |
| 2021-02-17 | 130.84 |
| 2021-02-16 | 133.19 |
| 2021-02-12 | 135.37 |
| 2021-02-11 | 135.13 |
| 2021-02-10 | 135.39 |
| 2021-02-09 | 136.01 |
| 2021-02-08 | 136.91 |
| 2021-02-05 | 136.76 |
| 2021-02-04 | 137.39 |
| 2021-02-03 | 133.94 |
| 2021-02-02 | 134.99 |
| 2021-02-01 | 134.14 |
| 2021-01-29 | 131.96 |
| 2021-01-28 | 137.09 |
| 2021-01-27 | 142.06 |
| 2021-01-26 | 143.16 |
| 2021-01-25 | 142.92 |
| 2021-01-22 | 139.07 |
| 2021-01-21 | 136.87 |
| 2021-01-20 | 132.03 |
| 2021-01-19 | 127.83 |
| 2021-01-15 | 127.14 |
| 2021-01-14 | 128.91 |
| 2021-01-13 | 130.89 |
| 2021-01-12 | 128.8 |
| 2021-01-11 | 128.98 |
| 2021-01-08 | 132.05 |
| 2021-01-07 | 130.92 |
| 2021-01-06 | 126.6 |
| 2021-01-05 | 131.01 |
| 2021-01-04 | 129.41 |
| 2020-12-31 | 132.69 |
| 2020-12-30 | 133.72 |
| 2020-12-29 | 134.87 |
| 2020-12-28 | 136.69 |
| 2020-12-24 | 131.97 |
| 2020-12-23 | 130.96 |
| 2020-12-22 | 131.88 |
| 2020-12-21 | 128.23 |
| 2020-12-18 | 126.655 |
| 2020-12-17 | 128.7 |
| 2020-12-16 | 127.81 |
| 2020-12-15 | 127.88 |
| 2020-12-14 | 121.78 |
| 2020-12-11 | 122.41 |
| 2020-12-10 | 123.24 |
| 2020-12-09 | 121.78 |

Now I hope someone will be able to help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In regards to getting a running average, have a look at windowed aggregates. I ***assume*** you are using a supported version of SQL Server.

Comment: I don't understand you. What I need is some explanation on why my query is not working, or give me an alternative solution.

Comment: See [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Also, for the sample data you've provided, what are the expected results?

Comment: RSI varies between 0 and 100, so I expect to see results in this interval for each day.

Comment: The OVER clause link does not help me either. It does not explain what is wrong with my recursion.

Comment: Documentation doesn't tell you what is *wrong* with **your** code, @Yana , it tells you how to use functionality.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, RSI uses an exponential backoff calculation. I believe you can do this with 13 `LAG` functions

Comment: RSI uses exponential smoothing not SMA.. 
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_rma

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Modified_moving_average